# sequelize hide fields after instanceMethods removed

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Since v4 sequelize decided to remove instanceMethods, which was used by me to remove sensitive fields such as password, in records returned to clients.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

My question is, what shall I use now, to hide fields like password in User table?

appreciate any recommendation

Comment: The new way to write instance methods is also provided in the same documentation. Did you try that?

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks Prerak. Yes I did, but unfortunately im working with typescript thus not really sure it applies the same way. Also I tried to use hook (afterFind), but afterFind doesnt seem to be executed after .create (I guess that's internally sequelize doesnt really do a find after creation?)